# Failure log from Dev Center

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-10, windows-store, windows-10-mobile, windows-dev-center

Recently I’ve release my **Windows 10 UWP** application in store .
Last week I released a new update in store ,after a week I receive lots of mail from users about a bug in my  app.(Pages that want to connect to database can't open and they crash)

Funny part is that when I deploy and run it by visual studio or Powershell (appx-package command) everything works fine, so I can't find a thing.(Even in RemoteMachine and Emulator)

So I was checking my dashboard in dev center and find some "failed log" there.

How can I use these logs to find my problem?

I'm really stuck and don't know what to do!!

[image: logs]
[image: stack trace]

Comment: What happens when you click on the *Stack trace* link??

Comment: @JustinXL In post update

Comment: Not helpful at all! Guess you will have to find a logging tool instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

In `Properties` of the Project there is a file named `Default.rd.xml` that contains an element like `<Assembly Name="*Application" ...`

So by mistake the attribute it was changed to `name="*Application"` (Don't know what changed that and VisualStudio didn't notice that.)